# how to sum table1 and table2 (simple sum)

Tags: php

How I can sum Table1 and Table2

If table1 have more than one entry status "0" and table2 also more than one entry status "0" then sum Table1 + Table2.

Example

Table1 have 3 entrys with status "0" and table2 have 2 entrys with status "0" then sum is 2 
Like first table = 1 and second table = 1

And if table1 have entries and table2 doesnt have entries then sum is 1
and if Both doesnt have entries then sum is 0

I tryed this if statements:

```
require_once('../../function.php');
try{
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->openConnection();
    $status = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact WHERE status = 0 ) AS contact,  COUNT(*) AS ordr FROM orrdr WHERE status = :status";
    $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
    $qry -> bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $qry -> execute();
    $count = $qry->fetchColumn();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}
if ($count['contact'] => 1 && $count['ordr'] => 1) {
    echo "2";
} elseif (empty($count['contact']) && empty($count['ordr']) {
    echo "0";
} elseif () {
    # code...
}
```

This is counting for notifications.
Status 1 is readed notification and status 0 is not readed notification.

I didnt finish my statements because I know this is wrong way to do it.

Comment: `=>` is wrong on condition. You should write it `>=`.

Comment: @ICE Yeah my bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(x.cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) AS cnt FROM contact WHERE status = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) FROM orrdr WHERE status = 0
)x
```

So you can use the following PHP code:

```
require_once('../../function.php');

try {
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->openConnection();
    $status = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(x.cnt) FROM (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) AS cnt FROM contact WHERE status = :status UNION ALL SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) FROM orrdr WHERE status = :status)x";
    $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
    $qry -> bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $qry -> execute();
    $count = $qry->fetchColumn();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo $count;
```

---

If you need to know the sums of both queries you can use the following:

```
require_once('../../function.php');

try {
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->openConnection();
    $status = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact WHERE status = :status) AS cnt_contact, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orrdr WHERE status = :status) AS cnt_orrdr";
    $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
    $qry -> bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $qry -> execute();
    $count_contact = $qry->fetchColumn(0);
    $count_orrdr = $qry->fetchColumn(1);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if ($cnt_contact >= 1 && $cnt_orrdr >= 1) {
    echo "2"; //both available.
} elseif($cnt_contact >= 1 && $cnt_orrdr == 0) {
    echo "1"; //only contact available.
} elseif ($cnt_orrdr >= 1 && $cnt_contact == 0) {
    echo "1"; //only orrdr available.
} elseif ($cnt_orrdr == 0 && $cnt_contact == 0) (
    echo "0"; //nothing available.
}

//simpler solution instead of "if" above:
//echo (($cnt_contact > 0 ? 1 : 0) + ($cnt_orrdr > 0 ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: Why not use just if($count > 0){ echo $count } ?

Comment: Its like notification count upper Bell 0 or 1 or 2 depends how many notifications, so cant use text "Not available" I can only echo numbers.